# Only allow requests to certain paths using k8s ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I've set up an ingress to route traffic to my http server, however I would like to leave some routes inaccessible from outside of the cluster.

Example routes:

```
/status -> end point to determine service status

/users/names -> returns users

/users/ages -> returns ages
```

current ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

this works currently but leaves all routes accessible. What I want to do is only have routes that fall under the `/users` path open, so that would be both `/users/names` and `/users/ages`. That would leave `/status` inaccessible from outside of the cluster. Is this achievable from changing the ingress configuration? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just specify the path that you want to expose via the ingress like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: my-namespace
  name: my-app-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: localhost
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /users # <- add the path here
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```